# Why is this ASP.NET method blocking, when it should be asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given the following method signature in a WCF service:

```
public string Query(string request)
{
    using (Log.BeginTimedOperation("Persist request"))
    {
        var messageCorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var payloadURI = PayloadHelper.GetFullPath(messageCorrelationId);

        PayloadHelper.PersistPayloadWithPath(request, payloadURI);

        Log.Information("My service request {MessageCorrelationId} {RequestPayloadPath}", messageCorrelationId, payloadURI);
    }

    // DoWork here, code removed for brevity

    return result;
}
```

and the corresponding extension methods:

```
public static string GetFullPath(string messageCorrelationId)
{            
    var folderDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var folderHour = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");
    var logFolder = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkFiler"], "Payloads", folderDate, folderHour);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(logFolder);
    var fileName = $"{messageCorrelationId}-{"MyWCFService"}-{$"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-fff}-{Guid.NewGuid():N}"}.{"xml"}";
    return Path.Combine(logFolder, fileName);
}

public static void PersistPayloadWithPath(string text, string path)
{
    var task = WriteFileAsync(path, text);
    task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task WriteFileAsync(string path, string text)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Serilog.Log.Error(ex, "WriteFileAsync");
    }
}
```

This code will block, if for instance the file is being interrogated by anti-virus (guess) or IO slowness to the filer.

So here is the great debate, calling a asynchronous method from a synchronous method in ASP.NET. To this day I still don't know if there is a reliable way to create a fire and forget mechanism. It's not that I don't care about the failure, I do, that 'should be' handled by the catch statement and the static Serilog instance.

While writing this version of the post, it dawned on me that maybe one of the problems might be in fact the logger and it's async wrapper around the File Sink.. will test that in a few.

Any help is appreciated with this bugger.

Thank you,
Stephen

**UPDATE-ASYNC**

```
public async Task<string> QueryAsync(string request)
{
    using (Log.BeginTimedOperation("PersistAsync-Request"))
    {
        var messageCorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var payloadURI = PayloadHelper.GetFullPath(messageCorrelationId);

        await PayloadHelper.PersistPayloadWithPathAsync(request, payloadURI).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Log.Information("My service request {MessageCorrelationId} {RequestPayloadPath}", messageCorrelationId, payloadURI);
    }

    // DoWork here, code removed for brevity

    return result;
}

public static string GetFullPath(string messageCorrelationId)
{            
    var folderDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var folderHour = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");
    var logFolder = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkFiler"], "Payloads", folderDate, folderHour);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(logFolder);
    var fileName = $"{messageCorrelationId}-MyWCFService-{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-fff}-{Guid.NewGuid():N}.xml";
    return Path.Combine(logFolder, fileName);
}

public static async Task PersistPayloadWithPathAsync(string text, string path)
{
    await WriteFileAsync(path, text).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static async Task WriteFileAsync(string path, string text)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignored
    }
}
```

Still blocking randomly, lick every 20-30 requests

Comment: You're not `await`ing the call to `WriteFileAsync`, but instead called `GetResult` which turns it into syncronious. Use async-await all the way up to the top level method.

Comment: @Alejandro yeah, that's part of the dilemma, using both async and sync in the same code-base.

Comment: I think what @Alejandro is getting at is, if this is ASP.NET, why is this a dilemma at all? Your controller methods and everything after can all be `async`. Make your `PersistPayloadWithPath` and `Query` methods `async` and use `await`.

Comment: I have made it async all the way through and there are still times when it hangs on creating the file.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your code is essentially sync at the moment, so sync/blocking behaviour is completely expected. Perhaps you should show us your fully async code that still sometimes blocks instead?

Comment: async code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root caused was determined to be an incorrectly configured [StealthAudit](https://www.stealthbits.com/stealthaudit-management-platform-product), a tool that we use to audit our filers. Once the configuration was adjusted everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

So it's blocking on the `new FileStream()`. [Looking at the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,845), the constructor calls a method called `Init()`, which actually ends up opening the file. So it is doing I/O in the constructor, which really it shouldn't be since you can't `await` it.

Setting `useAsync` *should* make it run async, *if it can*. But maybe it can't open the file from a network drive asynchronously.

So your best bet is to just run it inside `Task.Run()` to guarantee it doesn't block.

*The following only applies to .NET Core (unfortunately):*

You would be better off using [`File.WriteAllTextAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltextasync), which would actually make your life easier:

```
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, text);
```

The documentation of that doesn't really explain anything for some reason, but it works the same as [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext) (it's just async):

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

So, exactly what you're doing in your code, but this way you can await the whole operation (including opening the file).

Comment: FileStream is async if you pass it the useAsync: true parameter

Comment: The documentation for the [`FileStream` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor) does say that the underlying filesystem has to support it... although if you are running this on a Windows system, it's unlikely to not.

Comment: The target location is a NAS filer, which is NOT a windows based appliance.

Comment: So I just realized that `File.WriteAllTextAsync` only exists in .NET Core. That implementation uses a method [you can see here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L672) which does kind of the same thing you are. So maybe what you have is the best you can do (unless you take the other suggestions and use `Task.Run()`). Maybe it's the fact that it's a network location that it's not working as expected. (maybe)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `WriteFileAsync` method. It actually runs synchronously until it hits the first `await` (that's how async/await works). I believe it hangs at `new FileStream(...)`.

If you want to just fire-end-forget form synchronous code, this should be enough:

```
    public static void PersistPayloadWithPath(string text, string path)
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await WriteFileAsync(path, text));
    }
```

The code above should help you when you don't have async alternatives. However as Gabriel Luci suggested in his answer you should go with `await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, text);` as it's probably optimized for async work.

You can still use `Task.Run(...);` with `await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, text);` in fire-and-forget scenario.

Just beware that exceptions from inside the task (`WriteFileAsync`) won't propagate to the calling thread. This won't be the problem in your case since the whole `WriteFileAsync` method's body is inside try-catch block, where you log the exception.

**EDIT**

To illustrate how the threads behave in async/await methods, play around with the following example (try all 3 ways the `Bar` function is ran):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Main thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            Task.Run(async () => await Bar());
//            Task.Run(() => Bar());
//            Bar();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task Bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Bar thread before await: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await Foo();
            Console.WriteLine($"Bar thread after await: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        static async Task Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Foo thread before await: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            var c = new WebClient();
            var source = await c.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com");

            Console.WriteLine($"Foo thread after await: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @StephenPatten The crucial part didn't change. `new FileStream(...)` is still running synchronously in your code. Try the Task.Run approach.

Comment: @StephenPatten see the code sample I attached, to better understand what's going on with the threads.

Answer (score 1):

I think it waits becuse you use

`task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

If you don't need the result, just remove this line. It should work fine.

If you need the result you should make `PersistPayloadWithPath` function also async.

Comment: If you expecting Log.Information and DoWork here, part to be executed immediately they will not with your last implementation. Your function will return to main thread without going under await part if the await part is not finished. This is how asnyc works. Did you try first implemantation with removing mentioned line? Without making your functions async?